# Need guidance on "float in from sides" project?

Tags: html, css, scroll, effect

I am trying to make a website with the following effect:

1. When you load the page, nothing is displayed
2. Then, when you scrol down, pictures will float in from both sides of the browser window,
   and then stack up in the middle of the window. (Like position:fixed)
3. When you scroll further, more pictures will float out and add to the stack ind the middle.

It's hard to explain and to find, but here is a very advanced example [of the effect](http://www.nike.com/jumpman23/aj2012/).

I really hope you can help.

Comment: Hi. Stackoverflow exists so that members of the SA community can help you with coding problems. If you can show us what code you've developed so far maybe someone will help push you over the line or at least nudge you in the right direction.

Comment: It's not doable with just HTML & CSS, you're going to need JavaScript to do the effect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set all your elements to display:none; in your css.
Use jquery for the animation:

- use [scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event to decide when to start
- use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to do the actual work.

For example:

```
$('#element').animate({
  opacity: 1,
  left: '+=50',
  top: '+=200'
}, 2000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
```

This will cause element with id "element" to fade in, while moving 50px right and 200px down during 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you that you look into using JQuery animations as well as searching for "infinite scrolling" or "endless scrolling".

JQuery UI is probably your best bet and looks good. There are several several ways to do this, too many to write here.

As for the infinite scrolling, there are also many ways to go about this.

Here's a start : http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html

Answer (score 0):

try this one....

```
   $(document).ready(function(){


    $("body").css("display","none");
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
    });
```

in this one, first of all whole page will be empty... then it will fade in....

```
    $('#element').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    left: '+=50',
    top: '+=200'
    }, 2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
```

use above code to move objects....

Answer (score -1):

you can use jQuery as well, it has good frame work for effect.